# DateListPlot shows longer time range than given in data

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

I have data as give below. The `DateListPlot` does show a data point beyond 27th March, that is not in the list. I tried to convert the date, set an according range .... I have not found a way to fix it yet. What is going wrong?

The resulting `DateListPlot`:

[image: plot showing extra data]

```
data={{DateObject[{2021, 3, 24, 19, 20, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], 33.7329},
      {DateObject[{2021, 3, 24, 19, 22, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], 54.0068},
      {DateObject[{2021, 3, 24, 19, 25, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], 51.6781},
      {DateObject[{2021, 3, 24, 19, 28, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], 23.9384},
      {DateObject[{2021, 3, 24, 19, 30, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], 21.7123},
      {DateObject[{2021, 3, 24, 19, 32, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], 45.9247},
      {DateObject[{2021, 3, 24, 19, 34, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], 39.5205},
      {DateObject[{2021, 3, 24, 19, 36, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], 13.1507},
      {DateObject[{2021, 3, 24, 19, 38, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], 34.1438},
      {DateObject[{2021, 3, 24, 19, 40, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], 36.0616},
      {DateObject[{2021, 3, 24, 19, 42, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], 27.4315},
      {DateObject[{2021, 3, 24, 19, 44, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], 29.8973},
      {DateObject[{2021, 3, 24, 19, 46, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], 30.3425},
      {DateObject[{2021, 3, 24, 19, 48, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], 35.5822},
      {DateObject[{2021, 3, 24, 19, 50, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], 37.363},
      {DateObject[{2021, 3, 24, 19, 52, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], 47.1233},
      {DateObject[{2021, 3, 24, 19, 54, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], 41.7123},
      {DateObject[{2021, 3, 24, 19, 59, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], 27.0548},
      {DateObject[{2021, 3, 24, 20, 1, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], 39.7945},
      {DateObject[{2021, 3, 24, 20, 3, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], 24.2808},
      {DateObject[{2022, 3, 24, 20, 5, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], 15.5479},
      {DateObject[{2021, 3, 25, 16, 52, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], 26.4041},
      {DateObject[{2021, 3, 25, 16, 54, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], 44.863},
      {DateObject[{2021, 3, 25, 16, 56, 0.00500011}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], 25.0685},
      {DateObject[{2021, 3, 25, 16, 58, 0.0100002}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], 18.6301}};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your data goes beyond `March 25, 2021`:

```
TimeSeries[data]["LastDate"]
```

[image]

`2022` is  probably a typo. So, we replace it with 2021:

```
data2 = data /. DateObject[{2022, a__}, b__] :> DateObject[{2021, a}, b];

DateListPlot[data2, 
 DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthNameShort", " ", "Day", " ", "Hour", ":", "Minute"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Ohhhhh!! I just got the data and I was assuming the date was automatically created. Poor assumption. Sorry, I did not find this one. Even though I tried to check the dates in the plot by coordinates.